# How can I use a class representing opaque bytes in an std::map?

Tags: c++, stl

I have some opaque bytes which I want to use in an `std::map`, both as keys and values. I created a class, `OpaqueBytes`, which has two (private) members: `_data` and `_size`, to store the bytes. My Cocoa background tells me that I would need to implement a hashing function and equality function on the class to use it in a `std::map`. Problem is, it seems like the STL requires strict weak ordering, based on [Can a STL map be used with keys of varying sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460880/can-a-stl-map-be-used-with-keys-of-varying-sizes).

I have several questions:

1. Is my intuition to create a class to represent opaque bytes correct? Is there a class in the STL which already exists to hold opaque bytes? In Cocoa parlance, is there an equivilent to `NSData`?
2. How should I implement the ordering of `OpaqueBytes`? I can't just compare the bytes using `memcmp`, because the two byte strings could be of differing length -  I wouldn't want FF EE to be considered equal to FF.

Comment: If std::vector<unsigned char> can't be used to represent "opaque bytes", what is it lacking then?  Vector can be used as a key for std::map

Comment: maybe the user wants to create a class to restrict the use, or change its copy semantics

Comment: for a `map` you need a less-than operator, for a `hash_map` (extension) or `unordered_map` (C++0x) you'd need a hashing function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to use OpaqueBytes as a key you will need a strict comparison. This can be a member function or a non-member function.

Could use something like this:

```
// assumed a friend
bool operator<( OpaqueBytes const& lhs, OpaqueBytes const& rhs )
{
   int res = memcmp( lhs._data, rhs._data, std::min(lhs_._size, rhs_._size)  );
   return ( res < 0 ) || ( res == 0 && lhs._size < rhs._size );
}
```

You could compare size first, of course. You'd get a different ordering but it would still be strict.

(I still think, as an aside, that map would be better implemented with a compare function than a less).